# Union and intersection probability

Tags: probability

Given that P(A) = 0.12, $P(A \cup B) = 0.34$. A and B are independent.

(a) Find P(B).

(b) Find $P(A\cup B')$

My attempt:

(a) Since A and B are independent, so $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B) $

Since $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, substituting $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B) $ would give

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A) \times P(B)$

$0.34    = 0.12 + P(B) - 0.12P(B)$

$0.22 = 0.88P(B)$

$P(B) = 0.25$

(b)

$P(A \cup B') = 1 - P(A' \cap B) = 1 - [P(A \cup B) - P(A)] = 1 - (0.34 - 0.12) = 0.78 $

Are both my answers correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, they are correct.